# Send android data to XAMPP server Java file input and then send back to android device

Tags: java, php, android

I am creating an authentication system where I get some value( let us say "x") after processing the android application. I want to send the value "x" to the server where I have a java file and it needs to be run on the server end(may be using php by passing the argument as the value "x"). After running, I need the output to be sent back to the android device to display it.

Leads how to implement such short structure will help me complete the system.

Comment: What should be used to implement such structure and any suggestions ? Seems the same was written above as well. Please learn to help rather downvote and demoralize new comers.

Comment: you can use openfire technology  http://www.kpblogs.com/mobile-development/android/android-chat-application-using-openfire-server-and-xmpp-smack-client/

Comment: Little clarification please. You have a JAVA file on server? What does it do?

Comment: it uses the data that has been sent from the android device, processes it and then sends it back to the android device.

Comment: Then why do you need PHP again when you have JAVA server running?

Comment: how to I post my data from the android device so that it can be used as a paramenter for the java file ?

Comment: Are you using raw servlets or any JAVA framework?

Comment: I am using XAMPP server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142811/discussion-between-ria-sen-and-mohammed-atif).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class that extends AsyncTask, and then use your php source that u would normally use for login. Here's a link that might help you out: [Android, PHP authentication](http://androidcss.com/android/android-php-mysql-login-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using HTML request. I am not sure how is this implemented. Any one can comment regarding it.